# Проблема с Ctrl+ колесико в Хроме

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть функции, которые приписывают к body height. Проблема в том, что в Хроме  Ctrl+ колесико не уменьшает, как от этого избавится?

```
var UserWindow = getSize()

$(function () {
    $("body").height(UserWindow.height)
})

function getSize() {
        var LocalObj = {
            width: window.innerWidth,
            height: window.innerHeight
        }
        return LocalObj
    }
```

Comment: Ctrl+ колесико уменьшает. А что должно на самом деле?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чувак, ты разрываешь мне мозг, если я тебя правильно понял, то при изменении масштаба у тебя хром не меняет значение window.innerHeight и соответственно не подстраивает body под новый размер.
Если я тебя правильно понял, то это должно будет помочь:

получаем размеры окна(определение размерф страницы сам вырежешь если захочешь):

```
    function ___getPageSize() {
        var xScroll, yScroll;
        if (window.innerHeight && window.scrollMaxY) {  
            xScroll = window.innerWidth + window.scrollMaxX;
            yScroll = window.innerHeight + window.scrollMaxY;
        } else if (document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.offsetHeight){ // all but Explorer Mac
            xScroll = document.body.scrollWidth;
            yScroll = document.body.scrollHeight;
        } else { // Explorer Mac...would also work in Explorer 6 Strict, Mozilla and Safari
            xScroll = document.body.offsetWidth;
            yScroll = document.body.offsetHeight;
        }
        var windowWidth, windowHeight;
        if (self.innerHeight) { // all except Explorer
            if(document.documentElement.clientWidth){
                windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth; 
            } else {
                windowWidth = self.innerWidth;
            }
            windowHeight = self.innerHeight;
        } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) { // Explorer 6 Strict Mode
            windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        } else if (document.body) { // other Explorers
            windowWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
            windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
        }   
        // for small pages with total height less then height of the viewport
        if(yScroll < windowHeight){
            pageHeight = windowHeight;
        } else { 
            pageHeight = yScroll;
        }
        // for small pages with total width less then width of the viewport
        if(xScroll < windowWidth){  
            pageWidth = xScroll;        
        } else {
            pageWidth = windowWidth;
        }
        arrayPageSize = new Array(pageWidth,pageHeight,windowWidth,windowHeight);
        return arrayPageSize;
    };
});
```

навешиваем событие на изменение размеров окна и на загрузку страницы:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("body").height(___getPageSize()[3]);
});
$(function(){
    $("body").height(___getPageSize()[3]);
});
```

Comment: забей, я с тупил по полной